# Uploading csv file from url using django forms

Tags: python, django, post, file-upload

So I am trying to upload and save a csv file to a variable via a POST to a url.  I have looked through the django documentation on file uploads found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/).  I just don't understand the use of a form?  What's the purpose in this situation?

They use an example with a form:

```
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

# Imaginary function to handle an uploaded file.
from somewhere import handle_uploaded_file

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file  = forms.FileField()

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Upload html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/" name="test" method="post">
    <input id="file" type="file" name="test" />
    <input id="signUpSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Upload(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="images")
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from app_name.models import Upload

class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
```

views.py

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})
```

upload.html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/" name="test" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input id="signUpSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```